# Form's font size changes size of form, even if size of elements is same

Tags: html, css

I have troubles with styling some web form. In my situation, form has inherited font size from body element. In the example, it is set to form just to illustrate the problem.

Have these two forms:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form style="font-size:24px">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

One would expect these forms to look the same as the elements of form have same dimensions in both situations. However height of the form differs as well as the space between input text and submit button. Can somebody explain what is going on and how to prevent this change of size? (I do not like to set form's font-size to 0px)

Comment: You specify `font-size` bigger than default `font-size`. White-space will be bigger too... So what is wrong again?

Comment: More trying to understand then saying something is wrong. Can I somehow get rid of the white spaces? Even if tags in the form are on the same line without space between them, the height of form differs.

Comment: Please provide SO Snippet to visualize issue

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have bigger text but you don't want to disturb any of your elements, then:

1. Either warp everything in a `<div style="position:relative;">` or give your `<body>` `position: relative;`.
2. Then wrap your text in a `<div style="position: absolute;">`

This should take your text "out of the flow", meaning that positioning, and resizing of your text should not affect any non-positioned content or layout. In addition, you can use z-index to "float" your text over the non-positioned (or more commonly referred to as "static") content. See **[here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)** for details